# Perfect hashtable for

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashtable, hash-function

I'm looking for a hashfunction which exploits the following requirements:

- N distinct integer values will be stored in the hashtable
- At any given point in time there will be no more than M values present in the hashtable
- Hashtable stays static for several queries (i.e. at some point the whole hashtable will be initialized and the following calls only read from the hash table)
- largest possible key value K is known at the initialization of the hashtable (K >> N)
- Every queried key-value pair is present in the hashtable

So far I'm using a hash-function like:
h(k) = 7 * k % M
with M = PRIME_CLOSE_TO(7*N)

7 is somewhat arbitrary.

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

In practice, any ordinary hash function would be fine.  But if you want a minimal perfect hash for some reason, you may look into a library that does perfect hashing, such as: [CMPH - C Minimal Perfect Hashing Library](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/)